# Why does gcc search header files from non-exist folders?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors, makefile

I am trying to build an open source project [shark](https://github.com/sharklinux/shark) on `CentOS 7`, and get very weird build errors:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdarg.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed/limits.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed/syslimits.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/posix1_lim.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/local_lim.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/posix2_lim.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/typesizes.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio_lim.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sys_errlist.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/errno.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/errno.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdint.h', needed by `core/luv/luv.o'.
```

After executing "`gcc -E -v -`" command, it outputs:

```
[root@centos shark]# gcc -E -v -
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.3-20140911/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.3-20140911/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/cc1 -E -quiet -v - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

So the searching header file paths should be:

```
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
```

I can't work out how `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8` and `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` come from. Could anyone give some clues?

Comment: This is a make error, not a gcc error, gcc's include path is irrelevant.

Comment: @user657267: So can I debug it and find the root cause?

Comment: The makefile's pretty simple, it's hard to say for sure but the dependencies might be messing up the build in some way, start again with a clean source root and remove `-MD ` from the `%.o` recipe (or change it to `-MMD`), you don't need the deps if you just want to build the source.

Comment: @user657267: After removing `-MD`, the errors still exist.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can reproduce on Arch Linux, first error is: `make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdarg.h', needed by 'core/luv/luv.o'.  Stop.`

Comment: @rubenvb: The `Readme` mentions using `clang`, but I don't think this is the root cause.

Comment: See this issue for a similar problem that apparently has not been solved: https://github.com/sharklinux/shark/issues/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author has uploaded files specific to his system to the source repository (see [this issue report](https://github.com/sharklinux/shark/issues/2)).

A solution is to find the offending files by doing a simple `grep`:

```
grep -R /usr/lib/gcc ./*
```

with the result (from a clean `git clone`)

```
./bpf/libbpf/bpf_load.d: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h \
./bpf/libbpf/bpf_load.d: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdarg.h \
./bpf/libbpf/bpf_load.d: /usr/include/elf.h /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdint.h \
./bpf/libbpf/bpf_load.d: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdbool.h \
./bpf/libbpf/libbpf.d: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h \
./bpf/libbpf/libbpf.d: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdarg.h \
./bpf/libbpf/libbpf.d: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdint.h /usr/include/stdint.h \
./bpf/bpf.lua:   local clang_cmd = string.format("clang -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include -I%s -I%s/arch/x86/include -I%s/arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I%s/arch/x86/include/generated  -I%s/include -I%s/arch/x86/include/uapi -I%s/arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I%s/include/uapi -I%s/include/generated/uapi -include %s/include/linux/kconfig.h %s -D__KERNEL__ -Wno-unused-value -Wno-pointer-sign -O2 -emit-llvm -x c -c %s -o %s", bpfinc, linuxinc, linuxinc, linuxinc, linuxinc, linuxinc, linuxinc, linuxinc, linuxinc, linuxinc, bpf.cargs_extra, srcfile, objfile)
./core/luv/luv.d: core/luajit/src/lua.h /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdarg.h \
./core/luv/luv.d: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h \
./core/luv/luv.d: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed/limits.h \
./core/luv/luv.d: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed/syslimits.h \
./core/luv/luv.d: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdint.h /usr/include/stdint.h \
Binary file ./perf/libtraceevent.a matches
Binary file ./perf/libapikfs.a matches
Binary file ./perf/libperf.a matches
```

Removing the offending `.d` files (`./bpf/libbpf/bpf_load.d`, `./bpf/libbpf/libbpf.d`, and `./core/luv/luv.d`) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't work out how `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8` and `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` come from.

These headers files get installed with gcc. They are copies of the OS header files patched to compile cleanly with gcc. Some native OS header files (e.g. on Solaris, BSD) do not compile cleanly with gcc.

---

> `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdarg.h',`needed by `core/luv/luv.o'`.

The above says that `luv.o` was built when `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdarg.h` was present. May be you built that `.o` file on another machine. Remove all `.o` and `.d` files or try `make clean`.

Comment: My OS is `CentOS`. So how can I fix it?

Comment: @NanXiao It looks like your gcc was not installed correctly. Was it?

Comment: `yum install gcc`, not find any error during installing process.

Comment: @NanXiao Alternatively, try `make clean`, the dependency files may be out of date.

Comment: @NanXiao Well, it says a `.o` file requires those headers. That means that `.o` file was built with those headers present. Remove all `.o` and `.d` files.

Comment: I have downloaded a new clean source code package, and build process still can't work. If possible, could you try it in your environment? Thanks!